# Why does the volatile make an undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, volatile

As my understanding, `volatile`-qualified value means that we must go to the addresse and take the newest value no matter when we access it.

Now I'm reading the book *Effective Modern C++* and I don't understand why the `volatile` makes an UB here:

```
volatile int vi(0); // initialize vi to 0
vi = 10; // set vi to 10
std::cout << vi; // read vi's value
++vi; // increment vi to 11
vi--; // decrement vi to 10
```

> During execution of this code, if other threads are reading the value
>   of vi, **they may see anything (e.g, -12, 68, 4090727—anything!)**. Such code would have undefined behavior, because these statements modify vi, so if other threads are reading vi at the same time, there are simultaneous readers and writers of memory that’s neither std::atomic nor protected by a mutex, and that’s the definition of a data race.

In my opinion, if other threads may see 0, 10 or 11, I can understand but why the book says that "they may see anything"?

Comment: The volatile integer may be e.g. a HW register modified by an actuator or some other external HW. So the value may be anything that the external entity sets it to.

Comment: unsynchronized access => undefined behavior => anything can happen. volatile isn't a synchronization primitive.

Comment: `volatile` is unrelated to threading. Use `atomic` or `mutex` synchronization.

Comment: Probably other threads can read `vi` after it is freed, which means the address that `vi` used to locate at no longer belongs to `vi`

Comment: `volatile` can prevent compilers from doing certain optimizations that would break a programs correctness, should it require to read a variable that is updated outside regular program flow. `volatile` doesn't provide atomic data access, or solves data races.

Comment: To clarify, the book is wrong that the value can be anything.  The options that it can be are very well defined for this particular code; since the bits that are changing are relatively few.  For example, at no point does the sign bit change - so you can be sure that the number being read will be positive... (note, the concept that the book is trying to make however is stated in the answers, this is just nit picking)

Comment: _"take the newest value"_ Define newest value.

Comment: @UKMonkey: _"you can be sure that the number being read will be positive"_ That is incorrect. Anything can happen, including opening up a wormhole and transporting your left arm to Tokyo. _"the book is wrong that the value can be anything"_ No, it isn't. _"The options that it can be are very well defined for this particular code"_ Literally false. _"For example, at no point does the sign bit change"_ You don't know that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I couldn't see that in the specifications - Tokyo wasn't referenced at all :(

Comment: @UKMonkey But it's UB, so left-arm-to-Tokyo teleportation is on the cards, along with nuclear Summer and C++ winning the Oscar for Best Carrot.

Comment: On a more serious note, there are a limited number of options that a compiler can do.  It can optimize things away - in which case vi will just be 10 (the ++vi and vi-- will be removed, and the initialisation will be moved to be 10), it can allow race conditions, where even if the processor wrote to memory 1 bit at a time, the number of options is limited or it can somehow (we wish!) detect this issue at compile time and abort.

Comment: Like I said - for this PARTICULAR example.  There are much better examples where you could try to force wormhole creation.

Comment: @UKMonkey: The specification says the behaviour is undefined, which means anything can happen. Those "anythings" need not be enumerated. _"On a more serious note, there are a limited number of options that a compiler can do."_ Again, no. The standard literally says the compiler can do whatever it likes here. And, in the name of optimisations, you'd be surprised how far a compiler will go with that. It might decide that setting the memory to all-1s first makes sense to it; suddenly, you have a sign bit for a while.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The Standard was never intended to define all of the behaviors that quality general-purpose compilers for commonplace platforms should support, but authors of "modern C" seem to believe it was.

Comment: @supercat: Well, this question is about C++, not C. And if you don't believe that writing strictly to standard has immense value, then I'm never going to persuade you not to write code that relies on UB. If a behaviour is documented by the compiler itself, then fine, but otherwise this just seems like a really silly thing to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It would have value, if there were useful standards that were applicable to embedded and systems programming.  On a platform where atomic accesses are expensive (or would require an OS that would be unavailable in a for freestanding applications), but the natural semantics of a "volatile" access would be sufficient, I would suggest that a quality compiler should support the historically-obvious way to achieve such semantics, or else document that it does otherwise for a strongly-compelling reason.

Comment: @supercat: This is why people don't tend to use C++ for baremetal embedded systems. Don't use the wrong tool for the job. And if you find a compiler that _does_ have such guarantees, and documents them, then it is the right tool for the job, and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is plausible that some hardware implementations might have two processors with a shared asynchronous memory.  If one processor happens to write a value just as another is trying to read it, it's possible that the bits might change literally in the middle of the read operation, such that the second processor sees an arbitrary mix of old and new values.  Worse, some processors can malfunction
badly if values change precisely as they are being read due to a hardware problem called metastability.

Whether or not any machines which can run C++ would have such metastability issues [hardware designers have learned a lot about how to avoid them in the last 35 years], the authors of the Standard didn't want to impose requirements that plausible implementations would have trouble meeting.

Answer (score 8):

This section is talking about the common misconception that `volatile` is safe for multithreaded programming. If different threads read from and write to `vi` at the same time, then you have a *data race* because there are no synchronisation or atomicity guarantees in place. Data races are undefined behaviour in C++, so that "anything" really does mean anything.

If correct atomic operations were used instead, then it would be guaranteed that all modifications to `vi` cannot be interrupted by other threads, so you would have no data race and your program would be safe. Alternatively, the synchronisation could be introduced using mutexes or similar.

See the references at [this site](http://c.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/) for more details about why `volatile` is not safe for this kind of thing.

Comment: An https version of the linked URL exists, but I don't have the rep for a 1-character edit.